# relative commutant of von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two subalgebras of $M$ such that $N_1$ is $*$-isomorphic to $N_2$.

What is the relationship between $A_1:=N_1'\cap M$ and $A_2:=N_2'\cap M$? Can we conclude that $A_1$ is $*$-isomorphic to $A_2$?

Comment: Of course not. A (separable) $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor can have a finite or properly infinite commutant on a separable Hilbert space. And since all separable infinite-dim. Hilbert spaces are isomorphic, you can arrange for $N_1\cong N_2$, $N_1^\prime$ finite and $N_2^\prime$ properly infinite inside $\mathbb B(H)$.

Comment: You mean we can take $N_1$ and $N_2$  are type II$_1$ factors and $M=B(H)$?

Comment: @mathbeginner A counterexample in line with MaoWao’ comments: Let $R$ be the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor (or really, any separable II$_1$ factor will do), $N_1 = R \subset B(L^2(R)) \simeq B(l^2) = M$, in which case $N_1’ = R^{op} \simeq R$ is finite, and $N_2 = R \subset B(L^2(R)) \otimes B(l^2) \simeq B(l^2) = M$, in which case $N_2’ = R^{op} \otimes B(l^2) \simeq R \otimes B(l^2)$ is properly infinite.

Comment: @mathbeginner You can also choose $M$ to be a II$_1$ factor. Say for the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor $R$, let $N_1 = R \subset R = M$ and $N_2 = R \subset R \otimes R \simeq R = M$. Then $N_1’ \cap M = \mathbb{C}$ and $N_2’ \cap M = R$.

Comment: @mathbeginner Basically, with just the conditions you wrote down, there’s no hope of controlling the relative commutants. Specifying the types of the algebras involved is unlikely to help you either. While I only gave type II$_1$ counterexamples above, it wasn’t really hard to write down similar counterexamples in type I, type II$_\infty$ or type III.

Comment: @DavidGao. Thank you so mcuh.  Would you mind recommending some reference books concerning the statements you mentioned above?

Comment: I have another quetion. I assume that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are subalgebras of $M$. $R$ is not the subset of $ B(l^2)$.

Comment: @mathbeginner It’s more a combination of several standard facts. How commutants and tensor products behave together can be found in Section IV.5 of Takesaki’s Theory of Operator Algebras I. The standard form representation of a tracial von Neumann algebra (which is what $B(L^2(R))$ means) can be found in Section 2.6 and Chapter 7 of Anantharaman and Popa’s An Introduction to II$_1$ Factors.

Comment: @mathbeginner I’m not sure what you meant by “$R$ is not the subset of $B(l^2)$”?

Comment: I assume that $N_1$ is the subalgebra of $M$. But in the construction above, $M$ should be  $B(L^2(R))$ and $N_1 = R$.

Comment: @mathbeginner I’m confused. What is the question then? What is the commutant of $N_1 = R$ in $M = B(L^2(R))$? (It’s $R^{op}$, assuming the inclusion $N_1 \subset M$ is the standard form representation.)

Comment: So if we take $N_2=R,M = B(L^2(R))$, then $N_2'\cap M$ is also $R^{op}$.  We should fix $M$.

Comment: @mathbeginner This is all under the assumption that *the inclusion of $R$ in $B(L^2(R))$ is the standard form representation*. If you just have a copy of $R$ in $B(L^2(R))$, its commutant could be different. $B(L^2(R))$ is isomorphic to $B(l^2)$ because all separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are isomorphic, and I already pointed out in a previous comment that the commutant of a copy of $R$ in $B(l^2)$ (thus, carried over by an isomorphism, also in $B(L^2(R))$) could be $R \otimes B(l^2)$.

Comment: @mathbeginner I did write “assuming the inclusion $N_1 \subset M$ is the standard form representation”, didn’t I? That’s the usual understanding when you write $R \subset B(L^2(R))$, but that’s not the only possible embedding.

Comment: (I guess the commutant of $R$ in $B(l^2)$ couldn’t be too different though. One can show, using standard theory of representations of II$_1$ factors, that it’s isomorphic to $R$, or isomorphic to $R \otimes B(l^2)$.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.